# TypeError - datetime.datetime is not callable

Tags: python

I have a class that I'm trying to call a `datetime` object on - I need it in a function as it is being monkey patched elsewhere. For some reason I'm getting an error. This is the class.

```
import datetime

class Boo(BaseOperator):
   
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def get_datetime() -> datetime.datetime:
        return datetime.datetime.today()

    def do(self):
        name = f"hello/{self.get_datetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
```

and the error i get when running it is:

```
    def do(self):
>       name = f"hello/{self.get_datetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
E       TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable
```

can someone help? I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: I've edited your code a bit so that I could reproduce the error without the rest of the modules/code you wrote (removed BaseOperator, super() and @apply_defaults). With that, it seems to work just fine? Could you confirm that is also the case with you?

Comment: This is part of Airflow, it is a custom operator that needs to inherit from base and that cannot be removed. I don't believe that is the problem. They should have no affect on this...

Comment: Could you just run this code in a terminal once? For me this runs without errors https://pastebin.com/g9TKp94W

Comment: I think I found my error. It was in the monkey patching... I didn't actually think that would be causing issues... I was monkey patching to return `datetime.datetime(2021, 11,11)` when i should have monkey patched to return `lambda *args: datetime.datetime(2021, 11,11)`. I feel silly now... thanks though!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my error. It was in the monkey patching. I didn't actually think that would be causing issues.
I was monkey patching to return `datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 11)`
When I should have monkey patched to return `lambda *args: datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 11)`.